# Find the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A linear transformation is defined by:

$T : P_2 → P_2$ is defined by $T(p(t)) = tp′(t)$

I am trying to find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis 
$B =\{ 1, 1 + t, t^2 \} $of $P_2.$ I cant seem to get the answer. I apply the transformation to each column of my basis:

$$T(1) = 0$$

$$T(1+t) = t(0+1) = t$$

$$T(t^2) = t(2t)=2t^2$$

Then i put the results in a matrix:
$T(a,b,c) = $

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right) \times \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{array} \right) $$

However the solutions say the answer should be
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right) \times \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{array} \right) $$

Why?

Comment: The entries in the columns are expressed with respect to the basis vectors in question, so $t = -1(1) + 1(1+t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

$T(1) = 0$

$T(1+t) = t(0+1) = t$

$T(t^2) = t(2t) = 2t^2$

But if you apply the matrix you have to these basis vectors you will see that this cannot be right. For example,

$$T(0,1,0) = T(1+t)=  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right) \times \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)  = 1 + t \neq t$$

You want to express $t$ in the basis $1, 1+t , t^2$ (as pointed out in the comment by Alex Wertheim):

$$ t = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You expand the answer wit respect to the basis. Note that the basis is supposed ordered base. So we have $T(1+t)=-1+1(1+t)$ that is the second column is $-1,1,0
$ there is no problem about other columns.